Getting Malformed input request when trying to use Claude Sonet Model by Bedrock
Got the below error -
software.amazon.awssdk.services.bedrockruntime.model.ValidationException: Malformed input request, please reformat your input and try again.
I am using below code -
 {
                    "anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31",
                    "max_tokens": 4096,
                    "temperature": 0.5,
                    "system": "act as a coder"
                    "messages": [{
                        "role": "user",
                        "content": [
                            {
                                 "type": "text",
                                 "text": "print hello in java"
                            }
                           ]
                    }]


Because in the JSON you are 1. missing comma at the end here:  "system": "act as a coder", and 2. closing curly bracket at the end } that's all

{
"anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31",
"max_tokens": 4096,
"temperature": 0.5,
"system": "act as a coder",
"messages": [{
"role": "user",
"content": [
{
"type": "text",
"text": "print hello in java"
}
]
}]
}

Updated the code as above, still facing same issue.

Seems that the problem is something different, I think the best thing for you is to refer to the official documentation:  aws docs

I have figured out my problem - actually I am passing a multi-line variable to system key, then it is providing me "malformed input error". If I am providing straight value to the system field ( as above example )- it works.
But my system prompt is a multi-line string, any idea how to pass that without any  issue???

My code - {
"anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31",
"max_tokens": 517,
"temperature": 0.5,
"system": "{{ systemValue}}"
"messages": [{
"role": "user",
"content": [
{
"type": "text",
"text": "print hello in java"
}
]
sytemValue = """
here is a multi-line prompt
"""

String nativeRequest = nativeRequestTemplate.replace("{{systemValue}}",
